# jooq connection pooling does not release connection

Tags: mysql, c3p0, jooq, apache-commons-dbcp

we tried to use dbcp and c3p0 as database connection pooling in our jooq environment. Both work fine for SELECT statements but CREATE and UPDATE statements does not release the connection.

We initialized the dbcp like:

```
public static DataSource setupDataSource(String dbUrl, String dbUserName, String dbPassword) {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassword);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
    ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory);
    poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Then we get connection for each query:

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
} ....
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
```

Out create statement looks like:

```
protected final DSLContext jooq;
public E add(E entity) throws Exception {
    E transformedEntity = null;
    try {
        R persisted;
        persisted = jooq.insertInto(transformator.getTable())
                .set(transformator.createRecord(entity))
                .returning()
                .fetchOne();

        transformedEntity = transformator.getEntityFromTableRecord(persisted);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        ...
    }
    return transformedEntity;
}
```

And in the end we close the connection with:

```
dbConnection.close();
```

The problem is that the connections stay open and after the connection pool is full no connection can be created. Do I need to close the statements and resultsets? And if yes, how can I do this with jooq?

Comment: It sounds like you are not in fact close()ing Connections realiable. Are you using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with jOOQ is to pass the data source directly to jOOQ. Instead of:

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
} ....
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
```

... write:

```
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(dataSource, dialect);
```

That way, jOOQ will manage connection lifecycles for you. Otherwise, I suspect you simply have some situations where your connection still leaks and isn't closed properly

Comment: So the after closing the DSLContext the Connection will be returned to the Connection Pool?

Comment: @M.Soldin: Why close the `DSLContext`? You shouldn't need to manage any resources when using jOOQ. jOOQ closes JDBC `Connection` instances for you, behind the scenes.

Comment: well i have multiple threads accessing database resources. After one thread is finished with database access it should return the resource. I thought this would be the way with a Pool Implementation. Or is it possible to access the DSLContext via multiple threads?

Comment: Your connection pool is implemented entirely behind the `DataSource` API. jOOQ will do the `DataSource.getConnection()` and `Connection.close()` calls for you, conveniently, so you don't have to worry about that. Yes, you can share the `DSLContext` instance among multiple threads, if your `DataSource` can handle this.